# Using sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been following [reign design's guide](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to use a pre-constructed sqlite database in an android app. I created the db helper class, and then tried to create a new instance of the class following the java tut. The program compiles and runs, but has been stuck on the last step listed for 10 mins.

My db is named sampledatabase, the apk is is Access Db.apk, and the package namespace is access.db. Thanks for any help.

```
[2012-03-06 00:39:47 - Access DB] Android Launch!
[2012-03-06 00:39:47 - Access DB] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-06 00:39:47 - Access DB] Performing access.db.AccessDBActivity activity launch
[2012-03-06 00:39:47 - Access DB] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'First'
[2012-03-06 00:39:47 - Access DB] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'First'
[2012-03-06 00:39:52 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-03-06 00:39:52 - Access DB] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-03-06 00:39:52 - Access DB] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-03-06 00:40:30 - Access DB] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-03-06 00:40:30 - Access DB] Uploading Access DB.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-03-06 00:40:30 - Access DB] Installing Access DB.apk...
[2012-03-06 00:40:57 - Access DB] Success!
[2012-03-06 00:40:57 - Access DB] Starting activity access.db.AccessDBActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-03-06 00:40:59 - Access DB] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=access.db/.AccessDBActivity }

    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //new instance of class DataBaseHelper

    public void main() {
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(myContext);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }
    }

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/access.db/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "sampledatabase";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param dataBaseHelper
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context dataBaseHelper) {


        super(dataBaseHelper, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = dataBaseHelper;
    }   


  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{


            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

        }
```

---

Logcat:

```
03-06 13:58:17.824: I/SystemServer(66): UI Mode Manager Service
03-06 13:58:17.984: I/SystemServer(66): Backup Service
03-06 13:58:18.004: V/BackupManagerService(66): No ancestral data
03-06 13:58:18.054: I/BackupManagerService(66): Found stale backup journal, scheduling
03-06 13:58:18.054: I/BackupManagerService(66):   com.android.inputmethod.latin
03-06 13:58:18.054: I/BackupManagerService(66):   com.android.browser
03-06 13:58:18.054: I/BackupManagerService(66):   com.android.providers.userdictionary
03-06 13:58:18.064: I/BackupManagerService(66):   android
03-06 13:58:18.064: I/BackupManagerService(66):   com.android.providers.settings
03-06 13:58:18.064: I/BackupManagerService(66): Backup enabled => true
03-06 13:58:18.074: I/SystemServer(66): AppWidget Service
03-06 13:58:18.074: I/SystemServer(66): Recognition Service
03-06 13:58:18.085: I/SystemServer(66): DiskStats Service
03-06 13:58:18.104: I/WindowManager(66): SAFE MODE not enabled
03-06 13:58:18.104: D/dalvikvm(66): JIT started for system_server
03-06 13:58:18.414: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 44% free 3823K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 28ms+39ms
03-06 13:58:18.434: D/PowerManagerService(66): system ready!
03-06 13:58:18.434: I/ActivityManager(66): System now ready
03-06 13:58:18.454: I/SystemServer(66): Making services ready
03-06 13:58:18.464: I/StatusBarManagerService(66): Starting service: ComponentInfo{com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService}
03-06 13:58:18.484: I/Zygote(66): Process: zygote socket opened
03-06 13:58:18.504: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.systemui for service com.android.systemui/.statusbar.StatusBarService: pid=115 uid=1000 gids={3002, 3001, 3003}
03-06 13:58:18.504: I/ActivityManager(66): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=en_US touch=0 keys=0/0/0 nav=0/0 orien=0 layout=0 uiMode=17 seq=2}
03-06 13:58:18.534: I/ActivityManager(66): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=3}
03-06 13:58:18.544: W/RecognitionManagerService(66): no available voice recognition services found
03-06 13:58:18.864: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn for service jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.OpenWnnJAJP: pid=122 uid=10004 gids={}
03-06 13:58:18.914: D/NetworkManagmentService(66): Registering observer
03-06 13:58:18.914: E/ThrottleService(66): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
03-06 13:58:18.954: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.phone for added application com.android.phone: pid=126 uid=1001 gids={3002, 3001, 3003, 1015}
03-06 13:58:19.014: W/GpsLocationProvider(66): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
03-06 13:58:19.045: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.systemui for added application com.android.systemui: pid=130 uid=1000 gids={3002, 3001, 3003}
03-06 13:58:19.214: I/ActivityManager(66): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } from pid 0
03-06 13:58:19.284: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.launcher for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: pid=134 uid=10013 gids={}
03-06 13:58:19.284: I/SystemServer(66): Enabled StrictMode for system server main thread.
03-06 13:58:19.524: E/logwrapper(136): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-06 13:58:19.554: I/logwrapper(29): /system/bin/tc terminated by exit(1)
03-06 13:58:19.594: E/logwrapper(137): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-06 13:58:19.624: I/logwrapper(29): /system/bin/tc terminated by exit(1)
03-06 13:58:19.654: E/logwrapper(140): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-06 13:58:19.654: I/logwrapper(29): /system/bin/tc terminated by exit(1)
03-06 13:58:20.124: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 152K, 43% free 3892K/6727K, external 2130K/2137K, paused 377ms
03-06 13:58:20.124: W/ActivityManager(66): Unable to start service Intent { act=@0 }: not found
03-06 13:58:20.184: W/ActivityManager(66): No pending application record for pid 115 (IApplicationThread android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@40642e80); dropping process
03-06 13:58:20.184: I/Process(66): Sending signal. PID: 115 SIG: 9
03-06 13:58:20.384: W/ActivityManager(66): Unable to start service Intent { act=@0 }: not found
03-06 13:58:20.704: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 9
03-06 13:58:20.704: D/qemud(37): created client 0x12f88 listening on fd 12
03-06 13:58:20.804: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'gps'
03-06 13:58:20.804: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 4
03-06 13:58:20.814: D/qemud(37): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 4
03-06 13:58:21.484: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 40K, 43% free 3892K/6727K, external 2729K/2770K, paused 501ms
03-06 13:58:21.574: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.settings for broadcast com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider: pid=164 uid=1000 gids={3002, 3001, 3003}
03-06 13:58:21.594: D/dalvikvm(122): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 54% free 2641K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 29ms+86ms
03-06 13:58:21.634: D/dalvikvm(126): GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 54% free 2640K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 11ms+77ms
03-06 13:58:21.874: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_CONCURRENT freed 407K, 54% free 2638K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+89ms
03-06 13:58:21.894: D/dalvikvm(130): GC_CONCURRENT freed 408K, 54% free 2636K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 7ms+48ms
03-06 13:58:22.034: I/ActivityThread(134): Pub com.android.launcher2.settings: com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider
03-06 13:58:22.324: D/dalvikvm(122): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libwnndict.so 0x40513468, skipping init
03-06 13:58:22.404: I/ActivityThread(126): Pub mms: com.android.providers.telephony.MmsProvider
03-06 13:58:22.614: I/ActivityThread(126): Pub sms: com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider
03-06 13:58:22.684: I/ActivityThread(126): Pub telephony: com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider
03-06 13:58:22.684: I/ActivityThread(126): Pub icc: com.android.phone.IccProvider
03-06 13:58:22.764: I/ActivityThread(126): Pub mms-sms: com.android.providers.telephony.MmsSmsProvider
03-06 13:58:22.874: D/dalvikvm(66): GREF has increased to 201
03-06 13:58:23.014: D/dalvikvm(122): GC_CONCURRENT freed 274K, 50% free 2936K/5831K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+4ms
03-06 13:58:23.715: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 172K, 42% free 3990K/6791K, external 3337K/3347K, paused 301ms
03-06 13:58:23.804: I/StatusBarManagerService(66): registerStatusBar bar=com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBar$Stub$Proxy@4068c018
03-06 13:58:24.074: D/VoldCmdListener(28): share status ums
03-06 13:58:24.084: D/StorageNotification(130): Startup with UMS connection false (media state removed)
03-06 13:58:24.174: I/StorageNotification(130): UMS connection changed to false (media state removed)
03-06 13:58:24.234: D/dalvikvm(164): GC_CONCURRENT freed 408K, 54% free 2636K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+59ms
03-06 13:58:24.385: D/CallManager(126): registerPhone(GSM Handler{40560f98})
03-06 13:58:24.544: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.CallLogProvider: pid=185 uid=10006 gids={3003, 1015}
03-06 13:58:24.644: D/dalvikvm(122): GC_CONCURRENT freed 421K, 49% free 3186K/6215K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+20ms
03-06 13:58:24.934: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 68K, 42% free 3997K/6791K, external 3201K/3747K, paused 351ms
03-06 13:58:25.174: W/ActivityManager(66): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService }: not found
03-06 13:58:25.274: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 53% free 2697K/5639K, external 2128K/2137K, paused 458ms
03-06 13:58:25.464: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyServiceState: 3 home null null null  Unknown CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false
03-06 13:58:25.714: D/AlarmManagerService(66): Kernel timezone updated to 300 minutes west of GMT
03-06 13:58:25.914: D/SystemClock(126): Setting time of day to sec=1331060305
03-06 13:58:25.488: W/SystemClock(126): Unable to set rtc to 1331060305: Invalid argument
03-06 13:58:25.598: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.deskclock for broadcast com.android.deskclock/.AlarmInitReceiver: pid=195 uid=10019 gids={}
03-06 13:58:25.707: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=radioTurnedOff interfaceName=null networkType=0
03-06 13:58:25.727: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=gprsDetached interfaceName=null networkType=0
03-06 13:58:26.257: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 162K, 42% free 4052K/6919K, external 4073K/5086K, paused 311ms
03-06 13:58:26.397: I/ActivityThread(185): Pub com.android.social: com.android.providers.contacts.SocialProvider
03-06 13:58:26.637: I/ActivityThread(185): Pub applications: com.android.providers.applications.ApplicationsProvider
03-06 13:58:27.177: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 25K, 52% free 2720K/5639K, external 2668K/2681K, paused 756ms
03-06 13:58:27.587: D/dalvikvm(185): GC_CONCURRENT freed 407K, 54% free 2613K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+64ms
03-06 13:58:27.868: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyServiceState: 0 home Android Android 310260  UMTS CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false
03-06 13:58:27.927: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=null interfaceName=null networkType=3
03-06 13:58:28.827: D/MccTable(126): updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=310, mnc=260
03-06 13:58:28.827: D/MccTable(126): locale set to en_us
03-06 13:58:28.937: I/ActivityThread(185): Pub contacts;com.android.contacts: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2
03-06 13:58:28.947: D/MccTable(126): WIFI_NUM_ALLOWED_CHANNELS set to 11
03-06 13:58:29.107: I/WifiService(66): WifiService trying to setNumAllowed to 11 with persist set to true
03-06 13:58:29.117: I/ActivityManager(66): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=4}
03-06 13:58:29.207: D/dalvikvm(126): GC_CONCURRENT freed 227K, 50% free 2927K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 8ms+108ms
03-06 13:58:29.327: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyMessageWaitingChanged: false
03-06 13:58:29.327: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyCallForwardingChanged: false
03-06 13:58:29.527: I/ActivityThread(195): Pub com.android.deskclock: com.android.deskclock.AlarmProvider
03-06 13:58:29.807: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 6K, 52% free 2732K/5639K, external 3368K/3387K, paused 889ms
03-06 13:58:29.888: D/dalvikvm(195): GC_CONCURRENT freed 370K, 54% free 2616K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 11ms+71ms
03-06 13:58:30.207: W/ActivityManager(66): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{405e49b8 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
03-06 13:58:30.297: D/PowerManagerService(66): bootCompleted
03-06 13:58:30.497: D/AndroidRuntime(199): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-06 13:58:30.547: D/AndroidRuntime(199): CheckJNI is ON
03-06 13:58:30.647: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_CONCURRENT freed 442K, 43% free 4090K/7175K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 6ms+14ms
03-06 13:58:30.787: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.protips for broadcast com.android.protips/.ProtipWidget: pid=217 uid=10024 gids={}
03-06 13:58:31.057: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 284ms
03-06 13:58:31.257: D/TelephonyProvider(126): Setting numeric '310260' to be the current operator
03-06 13:58:31.367: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyDataConnection: state=1 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=simLoaded interfaceName=null networkType=3
03-06 13:58:31.487: I/TelephonyRegistry(66): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=simLoaded interfaceName=/dev/omap_csmi_tty1 networkType=3
03-06 13:58:31.617: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 488ms
03-06 13:58:31.718: D/Tethering(66): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
03-06 13:58:31.947: D/SntpClient(66): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
03-06 13:58:32.027: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 283ms
03-06 13:58:32.517: I/ActivityThread(185): Pub call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider
03-06 13:58:32.577: I/ActivityThread(185): Pub user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
03-06 13:58:32.727: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android.music/.MediaAppWidgetProvider: pid=232 uid=10005 gids={3003, 1015}
03-06 13:58:32.827: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 51% free 2779K/5639K, external 4217K/4261K, paused 228ms
03-06 13:58:33.118: I/SearchManagerService(66): Building list of searchable activities
03-06 13:58:33.857: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.quicksearchbox for broadcast com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchWidgetProvider: pid=241 uid=10002 gids={3003}
03-06 13:58:33.927: D/AndroidRuntime(199): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
03-06 13:58:33.927: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 28K, 51% free 2800K/5639K, external 5345K/5346K, paused 266ms
03-06 13:58:34.167: W/WindowManager(66): App freeze timeout expired.
03-06 13:58:34.167: W/WindowManager(66): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{40609a78 token=HistoryRecord{405e49b8 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}}
03-06 13:58:34.247: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=251 uid=10003 gids={1015, 2001}
03-06 13:58:34.257: D/dalvikvm(66): GREF has increased to 301
03-06 13:58:34.448: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 51% free 2806K/5639K, external 5417K/6692K, paused 298ms
03-06 13:58:35.017: I/ActivityThread(241): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.google: com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSuggestionProvider
03-06 13:58:35.107: I/ActivityThread(241): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.shortcuts: com.android.quicksearchbox.ShortcutsProvider
03-06 13:58:35.257: D/OtaStartupReceiver(126): Not a CDMA phone, no need to process OTA
03-06 13:58:35.298: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc android.process.media for broadcast com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadReceiver: pid=261 uid=10000 gids={1015, 1006, 2001, 3003}
03-06 13:58:35.317: I/RecoverySystem(66): No recovery log file
03-06 13:58:36.367: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXPLICIT freed 500K, 44% free 4107K/7303K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 181ms
03-06 13:58:36.437: I/ActivityThread(261): Pub media: com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider
03-06 13:58:36.607: V/MediaProvider(261): Attached volume: internal
03-06 13:58:36.667: I/ActivityThread(261): Pub downloads: com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider
03-06 13:58:36.787: I/ActivityThread(261): Pub drm: com.android.providers.drm.DrmProvider
03-06 13:58:37.017: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.mms for broadcast com.android.mms/.transaction.MmsSystemEventReceiver: pid=272 uid=10015 gids={3003, 1015}
03-06 13:58:38.207: I/SurfaceFlinger(66): Boot is finished (26914 ms)
03-06 13:58:38.288: I/ARMAssembler(66): generated scanline__00000177:03010104_00000002_00000000 [ 44 ipp] (66 ins) at [0x44620290:0x44620398] in 899732 ns
03-06 13:58:38.288: I/ARMAssembler(66): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00000001_00000000 [ 73 ipp] (95 ins) at [0x446203a0:0x4462051c] in 811985 ns
03-06 13:58:38.478: I/ActivityThread(272): Pub com.android.mms.SuggestionsProvider: com.android.mms.SuggestionsProvider
03-06 13:58:39.257: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.android.email for broadcast com.android.email/.service.EmailBroadcastReceiver: pid=292 uid=10028 gids={3003, 1015}
03-06 13:58:39.917: I/ActivityThread(292): Pub com.android.email.provider: com.android.email.provider.EmailProvider
03-06 13:58:39.957: I/ActivityThread(292): Pub com.android.email.attachmentprovider: com.android.email.provider.AttachmentProvider
03-06 13:58:39.957: I/ActivityThread(292): Pub com.android.exchange.provider: com.android.exchange.provider.ExchangeProvider
03-06 13:58:40.107: D/EAS SyncManager(292): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
03-06 13:58:40.867: D/Eas Debug(292): Logging: 
03-06 13:58:40.927: D/EAS SyncManager(292): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
03-06 13:58:41.007: D/MediaScannerService(261): start scanning volume internal
03-06 13:58:41.197: D/Email(292): BOOT_COMPLETED
03-06 13:58:41.297: D/EAS SyncManager(292): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
03-06 13:58:41.329: D/EAS SyncManager(292): !!! EAS SyncManager, onStartCommand
03-06 13:58:41.508: D/dalvikvm(251): GC_EXPLICIT freed 315K, 54% free 2543K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 236ms
03-06 13:58:41.659: D/EAS SyncManager(292): !!! EAS SyncManager, stopping self
03-06 13:58:41.667: D/EAS SyncManager(292): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
03-06 13:58:41.897: W/ActivityManager(66): No content provider found for: 
03-06 13:58:41.967: D/dalvikvm(126): GREF has increased to 201
03-06 13:58:42.017: W/ActivityManager(66): No content provider found for: 
03-06 13:58:42.047: D/PackageParser(66): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-1212845771.tmp
03-06 13:58:42.517: D/MediaScanner(261):  prescan time: 701ms
03-06 13:58:42.517: D/MediaScanner(261):     scan time: 69ms
03-06 13:58:42.517: D/MediaScanner(261): postscan time: 0ms
03-06 13:58:42.517: D/MediaScanner(261):    total time: 770ms
03-06 13:58:42.679: I/PackageManager(66): Removing non-system package:access.db
03-06 13:58:43.007: D/PackageManager(66): Scanning package access.db
03-06 13:58:43.007: I/PackageManager(66): Package access.db codePath changed from /data/app/access.db-2.apk to /data/app/access.db-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
03-06 13:58:43.019: I/PackageManager(66): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/access.db-1.apk
03-06 13:58:43.037: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/access.db-1.apk' ---
03-06 13:58:43.217: D/dalvikvm(311): DexOpt: load 30ms, verify+opt 32ms
03-06 13:58:43.227: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/access.db-1.apk' (success) ---
**03-06 13:58:43.237: W/PackageManager(66): Code path for pkg : access.db changing from /data/app/access.db-2.apk to /data/app/access.db-1.apk
03-06 13:58:43.237: W/PackageManager(66): Resource path for pkg : access.db changing from /data/app/access.db-2.apk to /data/app/access.db-1.apk**
03-06 13:58:43.237: D/PackageManager(66):   Activities: access.db.AccessDBActivity
03-06 13:58:43.397: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 258K, 49% free 3011K/5895K, external 6685K/6692K, paused 76ms
03-06 13:58:43.557: I/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@access.db-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@access.db-1.apk@classes.dex
03-06 13:58:43.557: D/PackageManager(66): New package installed in /data/app/access.db-1.apk
03-06 13:58:43.727: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 104K, 51% free 2925K/5895K, external 4753K/5582K, paused 61ms
03-06 13:58:44.428: I/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package access.db uid=10035
03-06 13:58:44.438: I/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package access.db uid=10035
03-06 13:58:44.547: D/MediaScannerService(261): done scanning volume internal
03-06 13:58:44.597: I/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package access.db uid=10035
03-06 13:58:44.757: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=313 uid=10009 gids={}
03-06 13:58:44.807: W/RecognitionManagerService(66): no available voice recognition services found
03-06 13:58:45.127: I/ActivityThread(313): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
03-06 13:58:45.247: D/dalvikvm(185): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279K, 52% free 2768K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 616ms
03-06 13:58:45.408: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1236K, 48% free 4238K/8135K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 103ms
03-06 13:58:45.467: I/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@access.db-2.apk@classes.dex
03-06 13:58:45.477: D/AndroidRuntime(199): Shutting down VM
03-06 13:58:45.502: I/AndroidRuntime(199): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-06 13:58:45.502: D/dalvikvm(199): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 293K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
03-06 13:58:45.508: D/jdwp(199): adbd disconnected
03-06 13:58:46.218: D/AndroidRuntime(326): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-06 13:58:46.218: D/AndroidRuntime(326): CheckJNI is ON
03-06 13:58:46.997: D/AndroidRuntime(326): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-06 13:58:47.038: I/ActivityManager(66): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=access.db/.AccessDBActivity } from pid 326
03-06 13:58:47.089: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc access.db for activity access.db/.AccessDBActivity: pid=334 uid=10035 gids={}
03-06 13:58:47.128: D/AndroidRuntime(326): Shutting down VM
03-06 13:58:47.137: D/dalvikvm(326): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 69% free 318K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
03-06 13:58:47.148: D/jdwp(326): adbd disconnected
03-06 13:58:47.187: I/AndroidRuntime(326): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-06 13:58:48.258: I/ActivityManager(66): Displayed access.db/.AccessDBActivity: +1s180ms (total +29s481ms)
03-06 13:58:48.258: I/ActivityManager(66): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +29s486ms
03-06 14:01:05.130: I/dalvikvm(66): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
03-06 14:03:32.877: D/SntpClient(66): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: Could you explain in brief that on which step it has been stuck?

Comment: On this step: [2012-03-06 00:40:59 - Access DB] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=access.db/.AccessDBActivity }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Comment: @YaqubAhmad, I'm having the same problem as listed above, even after following your directions. Is my call wrong? o_o

Comment: 1- Check that the database is copied to /data/data/packagename/databases/yourdatabase
2- provide the complete LogCat trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the SQLiteOpenHelper wrong. The onCreate method is called when something tries to access the DB and it is not found. Implement your DB table creations here (or better call the methods that do). Your DB will be created and the initial request completed. You can program the logic of a DB update in the onUpdate method. Android calls onUpate() if a higher version DB is given than what the DB currently has (in the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor).

Be careful extending SQLiteOpenHelper as a utility class. Every time make and instance of this class you also create an SQLiteOpenHelper object and all that it inherits from. Don't add to the heap if u don't need too